# Python passing QtDesigner class as dynamic argument to class in external file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, qt-designer

I want to be able to pass in any QT class object between two Python classes in separate *.py files.  I researched this on-line and within SO before posting.  I'm not that skilled in OO or Python.

First py file was created in QT_designer (5.11): rs485ConfigMenu with class Ui_rs485ConfigMenu(object), with *from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets*.  Not touching that code.

I wrote a second python (python 3.5) file with a class that should accept the Ui_rs485ConfigMenu.  I know that the second argument for the class is wrong, but I don't know how to pass in the Ui class for any Ui object as needed (e.g., Ui_menu01 vs. Ui_menu02, etc.).

My code for the second, separate python file and its class is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
widgetList = [ "QPushButton", "QCheckBox", "QDialogButtonBox", "QLineEdit", "QRadioButton", "QComboBox", "QLabel"]

class widgetListMethod( QMainWindow, Ui_menu ):
    def __init__(self):
        super( widgetListMethod, self ).__init__()
#        Ui_mainMenu.__init__(self)
#        self.setupUi(self)

    def iterThroughWidgets(self):
        menuWidgets = {}
        i = 0

        b = self.mainMenuFrame.children()
        #need general menuFrame name for all menus
        #need way of checking all instances in widgetList

        for w in b:

            flag1 = 0
            string0 = str(type(w))
            string1 = string0.split("PyQt5.QtWidgets.")
            string2 = string1[1]
            string3 = string2.split("'")
            if not set(string3).isdisjoint(widgetList):

               widgetText = w.text()
               labelValue = widgetText.split("_value")

               if isinstance( w, QLabel ) and len( labelValue ) > 1:
                   #keep only those QLabels that have .value in label
                   i = i + 1
                   flag1 = 1
                elif not isinstance( w, QLabel ):
                  i = i + 1
                  flag1 = 1

                if flag1 == 1:
                  x = w.geometry().x()
                  y = w.geometry().y()
                  menuWidgets[i] = [x, y, widgetText, w ]
        return menuWidgets
```

---

Ui code from QtDesigner alone exceeds length for characters of 3000 by another 3000+.  Cannot paste Ui and py code.  Happy to send on or provide link from safe-site.

Comment: What type of form did you create the .ui in Qt Designer?

Comment: Thanks.  I used QMainWindow from templates/forms.  Can post code fro QtDesigner as *.py file as needed.

Comment: show the .ui and .py file

Comment: Can I post these files?  Pasting and indenting will take a long time.

Comment: You have to paste the code, select the code and press `Ctrl + K`